# Ansible-Playbook to Install postgresql

Tags: ansible, devops

can anyone help me with an ansible playbook to install Postgresql on the windows node. I have gone through ansible docs but I am not getting ansible-playbook

Comment: Please do not ask for ready-made solutions. What have you tried before? if you are stuck what is the problem?